# Best practices for shared image folder on a Linux cluster?

Tags: linux, tomcat, centos, cluster-computing

I'm building a web app that will scale into a linux cluster with tomcat and nginx. There will be one nginx web server load balancing multiple tomcat app servers. And a database server in behind. All running on CentOS 6.

The app involves users uploading photos. I plan to keep all the images on the file system of the front nginx box and have pointers to them stored in the database. This way nginx can serve them full speed without involving the app servers.

The app resizes the image in the browser before uploading. So file size will not be too extreme.

What is the most efficient/reliable way of writing the images from the app servers to the nginx front end server? I can think of several ways I could do it. But I suspect some kind of network files system would be best.

What are current best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not use CMS (Content Management System), you could use the following options :

If you have only one front end web server then the suggestion would be to store it locally on the web server in a local Unix filesystem.

If you have multiple web servers, you could store the files on a SAN or NAS shared network device. This way you would not need to synchronize the files across the servers. Make sure that the shared resource is redundant else if it goes down, your site will be down.